# ubuntu 18.04 add package lsb-cxx

Tags: 18.04

How to install package lsb-cxx?
i did following

> $ apt install lsb-cxx

which result in

> Reading package lists... Done
>   Building dependency tree
>   Reading state information... Done
>   **E: Unable to locate package lsb-cxx**

Comment: What is `lsb-cxx`? Which guide or software recommends to install it?

Comment: lsb-cxx was dropped by upstream with the release of LSB 5.0 back in 2015. Ubuntu dropped the package sometime after 14.04. It's not in Ubuntu 16.04 or newer. You can probably find an old version on Launchpad or in Debian, but it may not be compatible with 18.04's LSB 9.2 packages. Most of the functionality is the same in the newer packages - they just have somewhat different names.

Comment: I followed following link in order to install oracle database,

https://tutorialforlinux.com/2018/05/09/how-to-install-oracle-12c-r2-database-on-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-64bit-easy-guide-installing-packages/

It has listed out lsb-cxx and pdksh and many others are not getting installed

Comment: I am also following this post, but got stucked.

Answer (score 0):

I also try to install **Oracle** and install a few require package which is include the **lsb-cxx** on this [tutorial](https://medium.com/venturenxt/install-oracle-database-12c-on-ubuntu-16-04-c081d51c0f9d), and then also missing the **lsb-cxx**. But I found the package on this [source](https://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/mint_upstream/rosa/upstream/base/lsb-cxx).